# Datatables server-side PHP using SSP class - how to group after join

Tags: postgresql, datatables

I´m trying to figure out how to group data from joined table in Datatables server-side PHP script.

The data for datatables in prepared by the PHP script using an SSP class modified for postgreSQL connection.

The table consists of products and their categories.

Everything is working well, but I cannot figure out how to prepare the SELECT statement in order to group product categories per product.

To make it easier to understand my problem you can see a setup example below.

PostgreSQL DB table structure:

```
Table: products_table
------------------------------------------
id        | title      | pr_template_id
------------------------------------------
1         | Product 1  | 1
2         | Product 2  | 2
3         | Product 3  | 3
------------------------------------------

Table: product_categories_template_relations
------------------------------------------
id        | pr_template_id  | category_id
------------------------------------------
1         | 1               | 1
2         | 1               | 2
3         | 2               | 2
4         | 2               | 3
5         | 3               | 1
------------------------------------------

Table: product_categories
------------------------------------------
category_id  | title  
------------------------------------------
1            | Category 1               
2            | Category 2              
3            | Category 3                              
------------------------------------------
```

Server side script (PHP):

```
<?php
$table = <<<EOT
 (
    SELECT
      a.id,
      a.pr_template_id,
      a.title as producttitle,
      b.pr_template_id,
      b.category_id,
      c.title as cattitle
    FROM products_table a
    LEFT JOIN product_categories_template_relations b ON a.pr_template_id = b.pr_template_id
    LEFT JOIN product_categories c ON b.category_id = c.category_id 
 ) temp
EOT;
?>
```

Current Datatables results:

```
------------------------------------------
Product ID  | Product title  | Category  
------------------------------------------
1           | Product 1      | Category 1        
1           | Product 1      | Category 2       
2           | Product 2      | Category 2
2           | Product 2      | Category 3
3           | Product 3      | Category 1                      
------------------------------------------
```

Datatables results I´m looking for:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
Product ID  | Product title  | Category  
---------------------------------------------------------
1           | Product 1      | Category 1, Category 2              
2           | Product 2      | Category 2, Category 3
3           | Product 3      | Category 1                      
---------------------------------------------------------
```

So basically I´m currently stuck at Server side script (PHP) and how to formulate the SELECT statement correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is:

```
<?php
$table = <<<EOT
 (
    SELECT
      a.id,
      a.pr_template_id,
      a.title as producttitle,
      b.pr_template_id,
      b.category_id,
      string_agg(DISTINCT c.title, ', ') as cattitle
    FROM products_table a
    LEFT JOIN product_categories_template_relations b ON a.pr_template_id = b.pr_template_id
    LEFT JOIN product_categories c ON b.category_id = c.category_id
    group by a.id, b.pr_template_id
 ) temp
EOT;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL there is [`string_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-aggregate.html) function (MySQL equivalent - `GROUP_CONCAT`) which can  compute a single result from a set of input values.

```
SELECT id, 
   string_agg(some_column, ',')
FROM the_table
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: For the time being I´ve chosen a solution where I use a "slave" table with product data prepared specifically for the datatables UI. It makes life much easier :)